# Opencart 2.2.0 Google Analytic

Tags: php, google-analytics, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am integrating googleanlaytics in opencart 2.2.0, some error is reflected

```
Notice: Undefined index: store_id in /home/domainname/public_html/test/admin/controller/analytics/google_analytics.php on line 13Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/domainname/public_html/test/admin/controller/startup/error.php:34) in /home/domainname/public_html/test/system/library/response.php on line 12
```

how can i resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics can be added easily into your opencart installation by opening file: catalog/view/theme/{your template's name}/common/footer.tpl

or if it's opencart 3.x
catalog/view/theme/{your template's name}/common/footer.twig

and before  tag you add you google analytics js code. Save the file and upload.

store_id is irrelevant with this task except if you added/installed an extension for google analytics that will provide a google analytics code per store (if you are using opencart multistore functionality)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply. I resolved the issue. It seems store_id variable is not defined in google_analytics.php 
**Replace**

```
$this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('google_analytics'‌​, $this->request->post, $this->request->get['store_id']);
```

**with**

```
$this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('google_analytics'‌​, $this->request->post);
```